# MYSQL - query to calculate number of records in a table, is it count(*)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Confirmation.

I created a database called transtest with 100 records.

Does this command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM example1
```

calculate the number of records in that table ?

Comment: its correct count(*) show the number of records from the table you indicate

Comment: great thanks just wasn't 100% sure, much appreciated.